# How to check last executed commands by users at FortiGate

Tags: fortigate, fortinet

How to check last executed commands by users at FortiGate firewall like `show cli history` at SRX firewall

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not possible to see any CLI history for all users. You can use arrow up to see what you entered yourself (in the current session). With the following CLI command you can see how many lines are stored in the history buffer:
`get gui console status`